# .Net Core assemblies in SQL CLR

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

Can .Net Core 3 assemblies be used in SQL CLR? And if not so, what will happen with the arrival of .Net 5? Or is it only possible to use only .Net Standard 2 and implement it as >net Framework?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can .Net Core assemblies be used in SQL CLR?

No.  SQL CLR is .NET Framework (even on Linux).

> And if not so, what will happen with the arrival of .Net 5?

Nothing.  .Net 5 is the next version of .NET Core.  It gets the big name because .NET Framework will [not have another major version after 4.8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/).  This is similar to the big jump from .NET 2 to .NET 4, in that there are breaking changes, side-by-side execution and lots of old applications that never port to the newer version.

NET. Framework is part of Windows, so it is not going anywhere, and it supports .NET Standard 2.0.  So libraries that depend on .NET Standard 2.0 can be used in SQL CLR.

Comment: So... how... (or when) can we load and run .NET Core 3 or .NET 5 assemblies in SQL CLR?

Comment: You can't.  And there has been no announcement that that would change in the future.  If .NET Core interop is ever added, it will probably be externalized like Python and R integration today.

Comment: Huge mistake on Microsoft's part. This severely limits upgrading to DotNet Core from older systems dependent on CLR. I suppose this is because SQL Server is still on the ancient code base.

Comment: SQLCLR is inside the SQL Server Engine, so tricky to change.  In particular SQLCLR relies heavily on AppDomains which got cut from .NET Core.  SQL Server 2019 supports C# .NET Core as a Language Extension running https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/csharp-overview?view=sql-server-ver16.