# Missing type from Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr

I'm trying to follow the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/getting-started-with-clr-integration?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=cs)

and I get to the first block of code before I get an error, `The type or namespace name 'SqlProcedureAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server'`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
  
public class HelloWorldProc
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void HelloWorld(out string text)
    {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Hello world!" + Environment.NewLine);
        text = "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

My first instinct was to download the NuGetPackage `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server`, but this didn't resolve my issue, as SqlProcedure isn't a type in that library. It's not in `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, either. I also tried `System.Data.SqlClient` based on a similar SO question. My assumption is either my .net isn't the version I need to be using - the project is set to 8.0 - but I'm not sure.

Comment: According to MSDN, this attribute is only supported in dotnet framework v2 - v4.8.1 [microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlprocedureattribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlprocedureattribute?view=netframework-4.8.1), the attribute itself is part of `System.Data` namespace in the dotnet framework.

Comment: In case you are not familiar with the differences between .net framework and .net core (includes .net 5+) - [confusion-about-net-vs-net-core-vs-net-standard-vs-net-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748330/confusion-about-net-vs-net-core-vs-net-standard-vs-net-framework)

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks. I'm admittedly quite rusty on .net; I've been doing Coldfusion for a long time... Are you aware of an equivalent in .net core, or is it better practice to just change the project back to 4.8.1 ?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to use .net framework. Just a guess, but since SQL Server is a Microsoft product and .net core (includes .net 5+)  is cross platform, perhaps that is why there is no support.

Comment: here's a related post to your question: [net-core-assemblies-in-sql-clr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078800/net-core-assemblies-in-sql-clr)

Comment: Did you notice the Tip panel right above the "Hello World" example on your linked page? _Loading CLR database objects on Linux is supported, but they must be built with the .NET Framework (SQL Server CLR integration does not support .NET Core, or .NET 5 and later versions)._ This applies on Windows as well - your CLR project must use one of the legacy .NET Framework runtimes, preferably the same one that your given SQL Server version uses. e.g.: SQL Server 2012 and 2014 use .NET Framework 3.5 SP1; you can pretty much assume SQL Server 2016 and later require .NET Framework 4.6 or later.

Comment: SQLCLR is only supported on .NET Framework.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. What I'm finding out is the technology has changed drastically since a lot of the related posts and questions, so it's difficult to find up-date-date best practices.